# How to count the no of rows and read the data in Excel sheet(.xlsx) in ruby using win32ole gem

Tags: ruby, excel, win32ole, ruby-1.8.7

I have a excel sheet(.xlsx) format which has only text data,I want to count the no of rows as well read the text data from the excel sheet in ruby 
using win32ole gem only.I have gone through many of the post in stackoverflow which represent these type of question but with the latest gem(spreadsheet,roo,etc).As I use ruby of version 1.8.7 and I want to read the data with win32ole gem.

```
Ruby Version 1.8.7
windows 7
```

Comment: `$Book->Rows->{'Count'}; ` check with this...where $Book is worksheet object

Comment: @ test can u elaborate it further,I am completely new regarding these concept.

Comment: I don't know how to use it I have sample excel sheet as sheet.xlsx,actually I don't have knowledge in retreiving the data as well as counting the number of rows

Comment: @test can u elaborate it

Comment: I used work.count but unable to get the count of the rows in the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'win32ole'

begin
 excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')


 workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('path_to_file')


 w = workbook.Worksheets(1)
 p w.Cells(1,1).Value
 p w.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ensure
 workbook.close
end
```

hope this helps.

you can loop through cells by changing the indices